# GraphQL and Laravel Lighthouse: types. Passing variables based on other columns

Tags: laravel, graphql, laravel-lighthouse

I'm building an app for my local sports club
We want to provide standard questions (5 per sport, category in the DB) and then capture the answers.
we'll then review those answers and approve/reject.

So I've got a few tables in my DB

```
questions
 - category_id
 - question_id
 - question

answers
- user_id
- question_id

assessment
 - user_id
 - category_id
 - approved
  ....
```

So, in my GQL call, I'm passing the user_id and I want to get all answers that the user has provided.

Here's my GQL Types:

```
type Assessment {
    id: ID!
    user_id: User! @belongsTo
    category: Category! @belongsTo
    selfAssessmentQuestions: CategoryAssessmentQuestions! @hasMany
    selfAssessmentAnswers: CategoryAssessmentAnswers! @hasMany
    submitted_at: DateTime
    reviewed_at: DateTime
    approved: Int!
    assessor_note: String
    created_at: DateTime
    updated_at: DateTime
}


type CategoryAssessmentQuestions{
    active: Int
    question_id: Int
    question: String
}

type CategoryAssessmentAnswers{
    id: ID!
    user_id: User! @belongsTo
    question (question_id: Int @eq): [CategoryAssessmentQuestions] @hasOne
    answer: String
    created_at: DateTime
    updated_at: DateTime
}
```

So my question is..
I can get all the assessments from user X.
How can I pass results down the line so to speak, to the selfAssessmentQuestions node.
I have a category ID based on the results of the lookup.. but need to get the category ID to the selfAssessmentQuestions call.
I have NO idea how to do that...

I can look the whole thing up in a 'normal' eloquent look up, but that just seems to make GQL redundant.

TLDR: Can i look up data based on results of another call, in the same 'type'?

Comment: Additional...
All Eloquent relationships are set up and working

Comment: I might need a bit of clarification. 
You are saying `but need to get the category ID to the selfAssessmentQuestions call`.

Looking at your database schema it says you have a `category_id` column on `questions`. So I would say you could just add a `category: Category!` field to the `CategoryAssessmentQuestions` type in gql?